# Trigger off PR or other pipeline Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up the triggers of my azure pipeline so that a build is triggered on either:

- Another pipeline completing on `main`
- A PR

I specifically don't want it running on pushes to other random branches.

I have this:

```yaml
trigger: none

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: remote-templates
      type: git
      name: name/repo
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: otherPipe
      project: proj
      source: Source
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - main
```

But it doesn't seem to want to trigger on a PR.

Is `trigger` interacting weirdly with `pr`?

If so, how would I accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was an override being enabled for pull requests.

I found this under:

1. The EDIT button on the pipeline screen
2. Three dots context menu
3. Triggers
4. Pull request validation
5. "Override the YAML pull request triggers from here"

Disabling that override made my triggers work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration for pipelines to trigger on pushes to Pull Requests can be found in the branch policies for a Repository, and is not stored within the `.yaml` file.

1. Navigate to the repository you wish to have pipelines triggered from
2. Select `Branch policies` in the `...` dropdown on the branch you want to configure. This is likely what you select when selecting a `Target branch` during pull request creation.

[image]

3. Scroll down to the `Build Validation` section, and click the `+` symbol to configure what pipeline to trigger and trigger options.

[image]

Note that this will have to be done for each branch you wish your pipeline to automatically trigger for.